# Single value reports in SSRS 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, reporting-services

I am creating a report to display values from scalar valued database function.
It is my intention that the report look like this having each of these values be discrete and not come from a single query. The labels are for display purposes. I am thinking of using a matrix control but that seems to work with aggregates.

[image]

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: Yes, the question is how does one call an SQL Scalar function and return the resulting value into a textbox? 

Thanks in advance

Comment: All data in SSRS needs to come into the report as a dataset.  You could have a single query return each of these metrics as a field in a single-row dataset, then place them on your report using texbox controls (I wouldn't use a table/matrix for a collection of single items and the type of formatting you want).  You may need to use the FIRST() function as a means of "aggregating" the dataset for those textboxes.  If you need the above layout to potentially repeat for multiple rows, place your textbox controls inside of a List control, grouped however you need (FIRST() won't be needed this way).

Comment: Thanks Kyzen, I get it. To save myself the effort, I used the functions in a SELECT statement with to return a single row dataset. Obviously scalar functions are out otherwise.